# Marmalade App deployment to playbook ERROR

Tags: marmalade, blackberry-playbook

I'm using the Marmalade System Deployment Tool to (Package and Install) an App to my playbook. It's packaging properly but when it gets the deployment I get this error, (ERROR: error running blackberry-deploy) and this is the log error.

---

SUCCESS: EVALUATION USE ONLY package written to 'c:\Users\George\Documents\Marmalade\build_helloworld_vc10\deployments\default\playbook\release' [took 3.05s]. This package is not licensed for commercial use
--> deploying to device from: deployments\default\playbook\release
[execute] blackberry-deploy.bat
ERROR: error running blackberry-deploy
***ERROR***

---

Would anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the standard License from marmalade. You need to buy either standard, indigo or basic license (I hope the names are correct).

You are currently using their 90 days free evaluation license, which does not support deploying on devices (Why should they support, if it's for free).

Comment: The license that I have is the RIM/Marmalade promotion. So basically the license that I have is a RIM license and it's supposed to be able deploy to PlayBook no problem.

Comment: Then I guess you are not using the correct SDK, they have separate SDK for this promotion, which is Blackberry only(From what I read). Or the possibility could be that, you might be having full SDK installed which is clashing with the RIM only SDK. Try uninstalling Full SDK and they rebuild.

Comment: Nothing is working and no one seems to have any answers for me neither on the Marmalade or the Blackberry forums :(

Comment: Have you successfully registered on Blackberry with a Vendor ID and entered it in the marmalade forum?

Comment: Also you can mail to the specific person about this problem at BlackBerryPromotion@marmalademail.com

Comment: Yes I did register my BB vendor ID with marmalade and I have received my playbook from RIM. I have gone through the setup of my playbook according to marmalade's instructions and all was successful. In any case I will try that email address and see if I can get some help from them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile a package but don't install, use this program for install applications, easy as piece of cake.

http://hatax.home.comcast.net/~hatax/bb/Playbook_Tools.zip

It's not the same download as mine 'cause I cant post numeric domains(IP) in this forums.
I almost turned crazy tryng to solving this. I hope it can solve your issue too.

Javi.

Comment: Personally not a fan of downloading programs from random websites.